# Persistent database connections with Catalyst

Tags: perl, dbi, catalyst

My organization has a custom package for connecting to our database servers that takes care of trying various mirrors at random (according to a config file) and only trying the master database server for non-readonly connections or if none of the mirrors can be reached.  I want to take that and use it to have persistent connections within a Catalyst app.

What I've tried is creating a Model package based on Catalyst::Model::DBI but that redefines that modules's connect() method to use our package's connection method.  Then I have redefined "selectall_arrayref", "do" methods that use stay_connected()...  It works ok but it's creating a new connection for every query - even during the same http request - although the documentation for Catalyst::Model::DBI seems to imply that the connection should be persistent.

So my question is, what SHOULD be happening? Do I need to do something different to get a persistent handle? would Model::DBI normally provide that? if so how do i graft this thing of ours into it, or is there a better easier way?  I don't want to have to re-write our whole package to use DBIx::Class, I just want to plug in our routine that gives me a database handle that's right for our system.

```
package SpamControl::Model::Database;
use strict;
use Freecycle::Database;

use base 'Catalyst::Model::DBI';

# redefine the connect method, this is just copied from Model::DBI but  using the Freecycle package for the actual connection.
sub connect {
    my $self = shift;
    my $dbh;
    # TODO: I wish this could be a persistent connection.
    eval {
            $dbh = Freecycle::Database::connect({ username => 'member', read_only => 1 });
    };
    if ($@) { $self->{log}->debug( qq{Couldn't connect to the database "$@"} ) if $self->{debug} }
    else { $self->{log}->debug ( 'Connected to the database')  if $self->{debug}; }
    $self->_pid( $$ );
    $self->_tid( threads->tid ) if $INC{'threads.pm'};
    return $dbh;
}

# for read/write connections
sub dbh_admin {
    my ($self,$c) = @_;
    my $dbh = Freecycle::Database::connect({ username => 'admin', read_only => 0 });
    return $dbh;
}

sub do {
    my $self = shift;
    return $self->dbh_admin->do(@_);
}

sub selectall_hashref {
    my $self = shift;
    return $self->stay_connected->selectall_hashref(@_);
}

...etc etc.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Catalyst::Model::DBI](https://metacpan.org/release/Catalyst-Model-DBI) provides persistent connections and automatic re-connections (through [DBIx::Connector](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Connector) nowadays).

If you have a module that already does that (`Freecycle::Database`?) you should not use `Catalyst::Model::DBI` at all, but rather use your module as a Catalyst model, for which [Catalyst::Model::Adaptor](https://metacpan.org/release/Catalyst-Model-Adaptor) can help a lot.

Comment: maybe i wasn't clear but what i did was just extend the Catalyst::Model::DBI, because our module does NOT handle persistency and such. It just handles connecting to the right databases (either master, slaves, or fallbacks) with the right credentials.   I looked at Catalyst::Model::Adaptor and it looks like more than I need. or less.

Comment: Maybe i wasn't clear as well: using Catalyst::Model::DBI (CMD) means that you should let it connect to the DBMS. If you make the connection by yourself, you're stepping on CMD's toes. Subclassing CMD could be a viable idea, but that should be limited to adding upfront your "round robin" logic to select the DB DSN and credentials IMO (cycling would only happen at app startup or in case of a re-connection though, as you want persistency).
Please, have a look at the following CMD doc fragment about CMD intended usage (2nd paragraph):
https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst::Model::DBI#DESCRIPTION

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  So it looks like Catalyst::Model::Adaptor is the only way to go.  But reading the docs on that, since my module isn't a proper object class (it just connects and hands back a dbh), it looks like unless I want to rewrite it,  i might have to wrap it in another module that creates an object, and then use CMA to "wrap" that. which feels annoying but maybe that's the only way.